# Two different edit form in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to implement 2 different edit form in jqGrid. I mean one normal usual edit form and the other with a much lesser form field (customized). both in the same navGrid. say edit and editpartial. can anyone throw some light?? many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons "Add" and "Edit" added by `navGrid` call both [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method with different parameters as the second parameter (`properties` parameter). In case of usage [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) called as

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {parameters}, prmEdit, prmAdd);
```

then `navGrid` calls

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, prmEdit);
```

if the user click "Edit" button and calls

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, prmAdd);
```

if the user click "Add" button.

In the same way you can add new custom button to navigator with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) method. For example

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: ""/*"My Edit"*/,
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-note", // some icon
    title: "My edit",
    onClickButton: function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.jqGrid("editGridRow",
            $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
            { // some options
                recreateForm: true
            }
        );
    }
});
```

In the way you add *one more* Edit button. The only thing which you need do now is temporary changing of `editable` property of some columns before call of `editGridRow` and resetting it to original value after call of `editGridRow`. You can use [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#add_on_grid_methods) method to simplify the work. For example if you want to make `myColumn` column editable you can use

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: ""/*"My Edit"*/,
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-note", // some icon
    title: "My edit",
    onClickButton: function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        // make "myColumn" temporary editable
        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "myColumn", {editable: true});
        $self.jqGrid("editGridRow",
            $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
            { // some options
                recreateForm: true
            }
        );
        // make "myColumn" back as non-editable
        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "myColumn", {editable: false});
    }
});
```

I want to emphasize that usage of `recreateForm: true` option for *all* usage of `editGridRow` (inclusive `navGrid`) is very important. So I recommend you just change default value of the option:

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, { recreateForm: true });
```

Comment: Wow.. this is exactly what i needed.. Thank u very much Oleg. your contribution towards jqGrid is awesome. (i have learnt much of jqGrid from your demos and answers).

Comment: @AbdulWahab: You are welcome! I'm glad that my old answer could help you too.

Comment: i do have two more doubts??1. where can i add events before submit 2. how to pass a different url for submit

Comment: @AbdulWahab: I am not sure that I understand you correctly. Do you mean `onclickSubmit`? If you call `editGridRow` directly you can use `url` as a [property](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties): `$(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, {recreateForm: true, url: "someUrl", onclickSubmit: function (options, postData) { return {myParam: "blabla"}; }})`. You can access `options.url` inside of `onclickSubmit` and change it it required.